# Algorithm for finding smallest subset in a graph

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm (not the code) to help solve a problem in python.

Given an undirected weighted graph with a number of nodes which represent military bases, lets say A, B, C and D. Each node has a weighted edge for the distance from one base to another miles.

A lookout tower can see in all directions for 15 miles. We want to place the smallest number lookout towers at the bases that gives full coverage from the lookout towers.

What would be the algorithm to find the smallest subset?

Comment: @PaulHankin Vertex cover is about covering **edges** with vertices. The question is about covering **vertices** with vertices. This is usually called dominating set, not vertex cover.

Comment: Yes, you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove edges whose weight is larger than 15 miles, and keep edges whose weight is lower than 15 miles.

Now your problem is exactly the [dominating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set) problem on the new graph.

In python, the graph library networkx offers two functions about dominating sets:

- [networkx.dominating_set](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dominating.dominating_set.html) finds a dominating set of a given graph, but does not guarantee that this dominating set is the smallest;
- [networkx.is_dominating_set](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dominating.is_dominating_set.html) checks that a given set of vertices is indeed a dominating set.